# Javascript / Ajax image gallery/retrieval

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, gallery

I'm still new to js so please bear with me if this doesn't make sense.
I'm wondering if it's possible to generate a gallery that doesn't refresh the page based on already generated pages.

Example gallery: http://www.theaustralian.com.au/news/executive-lifestyle/gallery-fn697wf9-1226045027371?page=1

In the example above, is it possible to make it so the image retrieval is much smoother so that it doesn't look like it's a new page everytime you click next/previous?

All this is based on the assumption I can't change the mark-up/backend. So everything has to be done on the existing mark-up.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need ajax.

You could do like do:

When the next button is clicked, change the attribute "src" of the image element and it should change your image.

Now you might want to use ajax to find whats the next image name; here comes ajax. You would probably want to use jQuery, Dojo, Prototype, MooTools.